# Why can't I access a form element id attribute using a dot syntax instead of an associate arary

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form with some fields being set to "read only" via JS.

I don't don't understand is why this line works in my code:

```
mainForm[readonlyElms[i].id].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

Whereas this line throws up an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined":

```
mainForm.readonlyElms[i].id.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

(simplified form):

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="fname">
 <input type="text" id="lname">
 <input type="text" id="dob">
 <input type="tel" id="tel">    
</form>
```

JS

```
var mainForm = document.forms[0];
var readonlyElms = [fname, lname, dob];
for (var i = 0, len = readonlyElms.length;
i < len;
i++) {

        //this line does the job
        //mainForm[readonlyElms[i].id].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");

        //BUT why not this line???
        mainForm.readonlyElms[i].id.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    }
```

I struggled to word the question title so please correct if the terms used are incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Because the expression `readonlyElms[i].id` is itself not a property of `mainForm`.  It's an expression that returns a _value_ which may be a property of `mainForm`.

Comment: why don't you just use readonlyElms[i].setAttribute() ? also, elements with IDs create global variable under the name of the id, which is how you can reach the inputs in your readonlyElms array. i guess mainform.ID would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines do very different things.

The first:

```
mainForm[readonlyElms[i].id].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

Gets the value of `readonlyElms[i]` and then gets the value of its `id` property, then uses that value to look up a property with that name on `mainForm`, and then calls `setAttribute` on it.

The second:

```
mainForm.readonlyElms[i].id.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

...looks for a property on `mainForm` with the name `readonlyElms`, tries to get the property with the name from `i` from it, then tries to get that object's `id`, and then tries to call `setAttribute` on that `id`'s value.

The reason for this is that the two syntaxes work differently:

Bracketed notation allows any expression within the brackets, evaluates that expression, coerces the result to a string (if necessary), and then looks up the property with the name defined by that string.

Dot notation uses the *literal* property name you type in the code.

So for instance, `obj.foo` is *always* looking up the `foo` property on `obj`, whereas `obj[foo]` is looking up whatever property name is held by the `foo` variable (which could be `"fluglehorn"` or anything else).

Sometimes examples help:

```
// These all look up the same property on the same object:

// Dot notation and a property name literal
obj.foo

// Bracketed notation and a string literal
obj["foo"]

// Bracketed notation using a variable
var f = "foo";
obj[f]

// Bracketed notation using the result of a concatenation expression
var o = "o";
obj["f" + o + o]

// Bracketed notation using the result of a function call expression
function bar() {
    return "foo";
}
obj[bar()]
```